# PHP sort dimension associative array while keeping array key

Tags: php, usort

I've array like this..

```
<?php

$a = array(
    "2" => array(
        "v" => 1
    ),
    "3" => array(
        "v" => 2
    )
);

usort($a, function($a, $b)
{
    return $a['v'] < $b['v'];
});
```

When I use `usort` to sort by the value of `v`, it return

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [v] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [v] => 1
        )

)
```

But I want the key not modified, e.g.

```
Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [v] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [v] => 1
        )

)
```

Is it possible?

Comment: use `uasort` for preserving keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [uasort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) to preserve keys

```
<?php

$a = array(
    "2" => array(
        "v" => 1
    ),
    "3" => array(
        "v" => 2
    )
);

uasort($a, function($a, $b)
{
    return $a['v'] < $b['v'];
});
```